# Shader reflection : variable name?

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, directx-11, sharpdx

How (if at all possible) could i get the name of variables / structure members in a shader from reflection?

I'm talking about raw hlsl shaders (no effet Framework / no D3DX, just raw directX).

I'm using SharpDX and found out how to get most of the information i need from the shader signature

```
new SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderReflection(MyShaderByteCode);
```

I can get most of the information i need, but while i can retrieve the sementic name (TEXCOORD, POSITION etc) i can't retrieve the actual name of the element (there's no "name" property).

Am i going about this the wrong way? Is this even possible at all?

```
struct Vertex
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float2 UVPosition : TEXCOORD;
};

struct Pixel
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 UVPosition : TEXCOORD;
};

float4x4 worldViewProj;

Texture2D<float4> diffuse   : register(t0);
Texture2D<float4> height    : register(t1);
Texture2D<float4> lightmap  : register(t2);
SamplerState pictureSampler;

Pixel PerVertex(Vertex input)
{
    Pixel output = (Pixel) 0;
    input.Position.z += height.SampleLevel(pictureSampler, input.UVPosition, 0).r / 2;
    output.Position = mul(input.Position, worldViewProj);
    output.UVPosition = input.UVPosition;
    return output;
}

float4 PerPixel(Pixel input) : SV_Target
{
    return diffuse.Sample(pictureSampler, input.UVPosition) * lightmap.Sample(pictureSampler, input.UVPosition);
}
```

What i can retrieve is "POSITION" and "TEXCOORD", what i want to retrieve is "Position" and "UVPosition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate trough constant buffers. 
Please note that is a Constant Buffer is not used, it will be stripped off the bytecode.

Attached code that iterates though all variables:

```
SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderReflection sr = new SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderReflection(mybytecode);
        for (int i = 0; i < sr.Description.ConstantBuffers; i++)
        {
            SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ConstantBuffer cb = sr.GetConstantBuffer(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < cb.Description.VariableCount; j++)
            {
                SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderReflectionVariable variable = cb.GetVariable(j);
                Console.WriteLine(variable.Description.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry i should've been more specific, this works only for constant buffer but what i'm trying to retrieve is the name of variables in structures that get passed as input/output. I found a way to retrieve the variable by name : new SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderReflection(pixelShaderByteCode).GetVariable but not the reverse (a list of the variable names). Updating my question with an example of what i want to get

Comment: Ok makes sense, you're a bit out of luck then, I don't think there's a way to do this (contract between shader stages is done by semantic, not by variable name, so it's likely compiler strips off that data). As drop said, parsing the file is likely to be the only solution.

Comment: Guess that's as good as it gets, that was still usefull thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible.

What you can do alternatively, is to explicitly assign semantic indices (in addition to semantic names):

```
struct Vertex
{
    float4 Position   : POSITION0;
    float2 UVPosition : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

and use them to uniquely identify your inputs on CPU side by reading `SemanticName` and `SemanticIndex` fields of [`D3D11_SIGNATURE_PARAMETER_DESC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another way that comes in mind is to parse source HLSL file directly (and so rolling out your own reflection engine).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm really only interested in friendly names (i want to expose them to the engine user). However i think i'll go down with HLSL parsing.